# method to know that video buffering is complete in android browser

Tags: android, webview, video-streaming, flash, buffering

I am playing a live tv channel in android browser using flash player.

Video takes some time to load in browser so i want to play some animation until video buffering ends.

The weird thing for me is how to know when will video buffering be complete in browser flash player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert in this subject - but i got this reference from another SO question itself:

[How to detect when video is buffering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863309/how-to-detect-when-video-is-buffering)

This refers to the event called `NetStream.Buffer.Full` event that could be your help.